# How to open a weblink by double clicking it in a tkinter list box?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to open web links that are shown in a list box by double clicking them.

So far all I have is the code that would work if a button was used to open to call the function as that is what I was using before but now I want to just be able to double click on it:

```
def internet():
    weblink = lb2.get(ACTIVE)
    webbrowser.open(weblink)
```

Im using python 3.3 on windows

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bind the double-click event of the list box to a callback function, and then in the callback check what item is selected in the listbox. So something like this:

```
listbox.bind( "<Double-Button-1>" , internet )

def internet():
    weblink = lb2.get(ACTIVE)
    webbrowser.open(weblink)
```

Comment: No problems, good luck with your project and let us know if you get stuck on anything else